# get the sum of a column + awk + double quotes + iterate

Tags: awk

this is my file:

```
$ cat -v test6 | head
"Rec_Open_Date"|"MSISDN"|"IMEI"|"Data_Volume_Bytes"|"Device_Manufacturer"|"Device_Model"|"Product_Description"|"Data_Volume_MB"|">20MB/30"|">200MB/30"|">2048MB/30"|">5120MB/30"|">10240MB/30"
"2015-10-06"|"427"|"060"|"137765"|"Samsung Korea"|"Samsung SM-G900I"|"$39 Plan"|"0.131383"|"0"|"0"|"0"|"0"|"0"
"2015-10-06"|"592"|"620"|"0"|"Apple Inc"|"Apple iPhone 6 (A1586)"|"PREPAY  STD - TRIAL - #16"|"0"|"0"|"0"|"0"|"0"|"0"
"2015-10-06"|"007"|"290"|"0"|"Apple Inc"|"Apple iPhone 6 (A1586)"|"PREPAY PLUS - $0 -"|"0"|"0"|"0"|"0"|"0"|"0"
"2015-10-06"|"592"|"050"|"48836832"|"Apple Inc"|"Apple iPhone 5S (A1530)"|"Talk and Text Connect Flexi Plan"|"46.5744"|"1"|"1"|"0"|"0"|"0"
"2015-10-06"|"409"|"720"|"113755347"|"Samsung Korea"|"Samsung SM-G360G"|"$29 CARRYOVER PLAN"|"108.486"|"1"|"1"|"1"|"0"|"0"
"2015-10-06"|"742"|"620"|"19840943"|"Apple Inc"|"Apple iPhone S (A1530)"|"PREPAY STD - $0 - #2"|"18.9218"|"1"|"1"|"0"|"0"|"0"
"2015-10-06"|"387"|"180"|"0"|"HUAWEI Technologies Co Ltd"|"HUAWEI HUAWEI G526-L11"|"PREPAY STD - $1 - #4"|"0"|"0"|"0"|"0"|"0"|"0"
"2015-10-06"|"731"|"570"|"2258243"|"Samsung Korea"|"Samsung SM-N910U"|"Business Freedom"|"2.15363"|"1"|"0"|"0"|"0"|"0"
"2015-10-06"|"556"|"910"|"13332272"|"Samsung Korea"|"Samsung GT-I9505"|"$49 Plan"|"12.7146"|"1"|"1"|"0"|"0"|"0"
```

this is the way I can get the sume of 1 column, I have to remove the " using gsub.

```
$ awk -F'|' 'NR>1{n=$9; gsub(/"/,"",n); sum+=n} END {print sum}' test6
684
```

What I am trying to do is achieve something like this [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/636681/count-the-sum-of-each-column-in-a-file) which iterates through each column.

```
awk '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) sum[i]+=$i;}; END{for (i in sum) print "for column "i" is " sum[i];}' FileA
```

this is my attempt(one of many) but it is showing `2000` for all columns this is not right, it should be `684` for column9 `$9`. **How do I achieve this?**

```
$ awk -F'|' '{for (i=9;i<=NF;i++) sum[i]+=gsub(/"/,"",$i);}; END{for (i in sum) print "for column "i" is " sum[i];}' test6
for column 10 is 2000
for column 11 is 2000
for column 12 is 2000
for column 13 is 2000
for column 9 is 2000
```

as and addon question, what would be good if I could achieve something like this for example:

```
>20MB/30 is 684
>200MB/30 is x
>2048MB/30 is y
>5120MB/30 is z
>10240MB/30 is aa
```

I have tried this using `NR==1` but did not get far.

**EDIT1** might be onto something here

```
awk -F'|' 'NR>1{for (i=9;i<NF;i++) n=$i; gsub(/"/,"",n); sum[i]+=n} END {print sum[i]}' test6
24
```

**EDIT2** somehow the `sum` array is not beimng created for me:

```
$ awk -F'|' '{for (i=9;i<NF;i++) n=$i; gsub(/"/,"",n); sum[i]+=n} END {for(i=9;i<14;i++) print i ":"sum[i];}' test6
9:
10:
11:
12:
13:24
```

---

### **EDIT3**

tks to the below answer, just need to do some formating:

```
awk -F'|' 'NR>1{for (i=9;i<=NF;i++) {gsub(/"/,"",$i); sum[i]+=$i}}; NR==1{for (i=9;i<=NF;i++) {col[i]=$i}};  END{for (i in sum) print "for column "col[i]"  the sum is " sum[i];}' test6
for column ">200MB/30"  the sum is 457
for column ">2048MB/30"  the sum is 86
for column ">5120MB/30"  the sum is 24
for column ">10240MB/30"  the sum is 6
for column ">20MB/30"  the sum is 684
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
$ awk -F'|' '{for (i=9;i<=NF;i++) {gsub(/"/,"",$i); sum[i]+=$i}}; END{for (i in sum) print "for column "i" is " sum[i];}' test6
for column 9 is 5
for column 10 is 4
for column 11 is 1
for column 12 is 0
for column 13 is 0
```

The problem was here:

```
sum[i]+=gsub(/"/,"",$i)
```

`gsub` modifies `$i` and returns the number of substitutions it made, usually 2. The above statement is adding up the number of substitutions made.  Replace it with:

```
{gsub(/"/,"",$i); sum[i]+=$i}
```

This modifies `$i` and then adds it to `sum[i]`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `|` as delimiter, you might use `"` instead (and get rid of the `gsub`):

```
 awk -F'\"' 'NR>1{for(i=9;i<NF/2;i++)sum[i]+=$(i*2)}END{for(i in sum) print "for column "i" is "sum[i]}' test
```

You only need to adapt the `for` loop to get values referred by an even index.